# How to read variables comma separated varibals from a text file into a javascript array?

Tags: javascript

I want to read text file's comma separated variables in a java script array
right now i have hard coded values like this

```
var arrUserTags = new Array('{{Name}}','{{Address}}','{{Company}}');
```

but i want to read it from a text file dynamically on page load
how can i read it?

---

I am done with below solution but now i am facing 1 more problem.
When i do changes to text file that don't become effective, while the browser takes the old values only? How to sort it out?

Comment: Is the file located on the server or local on the users computer?

Comment: i'll put it to server, but right now on local machine.

Comment: You have to reload the page or rerun the AJAX for changes to become effective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need AJAX to load the file:

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", path, true);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
```

And then Split the text:

```
function parse (text) {
    var array = text.split(",");
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: Should i use this code to my header section in the page?
Where i can give path like this
 xmlhttp.open("GET", /TinyEditor/TextFile.txt, true);

Comment: This is javascript, so you can use it in every script block on your website, if i got your question right. You need to put the path in quotes: xmlhttp.open("GET", "/TinyEditor/TextFile.txt", true);

Comment: through debugger i see data is fetched, but it gives me error

ReferenceError: array is not defined

Comment: Even i see the the function  parse is not called sometimes, o have put this whole code in my header under java script section.

Comment: The variable array is only defined in the function parse, you have to work with it there, or save it global. If your files are local, there is a bug: xmlhttp.status being 0 instead of 200.

Comment: mine is on server, i am getting data in response but it doesn't split to array variables, i see no data in array variables.

Comment: I have defined my varibale global and did like this
arrUserTags=xmlhttp.responseText.split(",");

Comment: I am done with your solution but now i am facing 1 more problem.
When i do changes to text file that don't become effective, while the browser takes the old values only? How to sort it out?

Answer (score 1):

You can not use Javascript (not talking about server-side js such as node.js) to read local file system files due to ***security reasons***, you can do so with some server-side language such as PHP, JSP, etc.